# android crypto implementation android 4.3

Tags: android, encryption, android-source

I am referring "[Android crypto implementation](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/encryption/android_crypto_implementation.html#booting-an-encrypted-system)" document. w.r.t Android 4.3 source.

In point 2 it says `The framework starts up, and sees that vold.decrypt is set to "1"`

But I am not able to locate the code that does things mentioned in point 2. Is anybody able to locate it? Is it somewhere related to class BackupRestoreConfirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple git grep will get the all the reference to this property:

```
cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp:276:    property_get("vold.decrypt", decrypt, "");
services/java/com/android/server/DevicePolicyManagerService.java:1869:        String state = SystemProperties.get("vold.decrypt");
services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java:239:            String cryptState = SystemProperties.get("vold.decrypt");
services/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbDeviceManager.java:173:        boolean dataEncrypted = "1".equals(SystemProperties.get("vold.decrypt"));
```

And I think the one you need is in DevicePolicyManagerService.java or SystemServer.java

Comment: Thanks, actually I did grep before asking the question. I was not able to find which one is in the actual path mentioned in point 2.